# UITextfield and null

Tags: ios5

Assume there's code for an iPhone project that is:

```
IBOutlet UITextField* numberDisplay;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberDisplay;
```

in implementation file and

```
@synthesize numberDisplay;
```

in implementation file. Also in implementation is

```
-(IBAction)numberClicked:(id)sender {  
   UIButton *buttonPressed = (UIButton *)sender;  
   int val = buttonPressed.tag;  

   if ( [numberDisplay.text compare:@"0"] == 0 ) {  
     numberDisplay.text =[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%d", val ];  
   }
   else {  
     numberDisplay.text = [NSString  
     stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", numberDisplay.text, val ];  
   }
}
```

When I run the app there is no display shown in the UITextfield, even though the connections were made with IB and is proven to be made by viewing the inspector. Even as a test if I add the lines

```
numberDisplay.text = @"a";
NSLog(@"the value is %@",numberDisplay.text);   
NSLog(@"the value is %@",numberDisplay);
```

I get " the value is (null) in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and rebuild your project, then double-check that the IB connections have been made to the relevant fields. If that still doesn't work, you'll want to try running the debugger and checking whether the UITextField is ever set or released.

Comment: im pretty new to this.  How do I start the debugger and what would i see to tell me the UITextField was set?

Comment: Thanks to all.  Started from scratch and all works.  May have been a mislabeled file.

Answer (score 0):

**Drop the IBOutlet from the ivar**, in fact drop the ivar, the modern runtime will synthesize it for you.

Drop the ivar, and change to this:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberDisplay;
```

And this:

```
@synthesize numberDisplay = _numberDisplay;
```

This line will automatically create an ivar named _numberDisplay.

```
-(IBAction)numberClicked:(id)sender {  
    UIButton *buttonPressed = (UIButton *)sender;  
    int val = buttonPressed.tag;  
    if ( [_numberDisplay.text compare:@"0"] == 0 ) {  
        _numberDisplay.text =[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%d", val ];  

    } 
    else {  
        _numberDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", _numberDisplay.text, val ];  
    }

}
```

Note from your own class you can use either `self.numberDisplay` or `_numberDisplay` to reference the text field.

There's a good chance you will have to reconnect in IB when you are done. Remember to disconnect any connections rendered invalid.

Comment: Put these in `viewWillAppear:` `NSLog(@"the value ivar is %@",_numberDisplay);`  `NSLog(@"the value property is %@",self.numberDisplay);`

Comment: the response to both is the value is null

Comment: Move those `NSLog`s to the very top of `viewDidLoad:` and check the result.

Comment: there are no messages.  The NSLogs didn't execute it seems.

Comment: if you go to http://buildmobile.com/how-to-build-ipad-apps-with-xcode-and-interface-builder/ you'll see all the code.  This is for a simple caluclator.  Only changes made were to change retain to strong.  Then I drag each calculator key to buttonPressed in owner and control drag number Display to the UITextField on the calculator.